# How to get a dictionary name from a list in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and stack exchange.  thanks for your help.  I have a list of names of dictionaries and would like to iterate over the list and retrieve values from the dictionaries.

my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.version)
variations = ('game75and15', 'game56and46', 'game52and52', 'game50and36', 'game50and25')

game50and25 = {
        'date': [1996,9,6],
        'range': [50,25],
        'arrayname': ['draw50and25']
        }
print('this is variations[4] ',variations[4])
iWantTheDictName = variations[4]
print('this is iWantTheDictName ',iWantTheDictName)
print('this is game50and25[\'range\'] ',game50and25['range'])
thisDoesntWork = iWantTheDictName['range']
```

the output

```
3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
this is variations[4]  game50and25
this is iWantTheDictName  game50and25
this is game50and25['range']  [50, 25]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tscript2", line 15, in <module>
    thisDoesntWork = iWantTheDictName['range']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The desired result is that:

```
 iWantTheDictName == game50and25['range']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, what you really want is, to select between n different dicts.

Eval would work of course, but would be bad style and have bad performance.

I would recommend a dict of dicts -- something like that:

```
MasterDict = {}
MasterDict['game50and25'] = {
    'date': [1996,9,6],
    'range': [50,25],
    'arrayname': ['draw50and25']
    }
```

You can put as many dicts into the MasterDict as you like.

To access one:

```
MasterDict[iWantTheDictName]['range']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `eval(iWantTheDictName)['range']`. The output will be `[50, 25]`.

Comment: That worked.  thanks.  I have been afraid of eval because of what I have read.  I am not taking any user input I am taking input from a file, so it may be ok ?

Comment: @RandyPerkins: You don't need to use eval. See my answer. Eval is not dangerous, as long as you don't put user input into it, but you still should avoid it, since it takes extra computing power. It is just not necessary with a good design.